# Cant' load data from external URL when using JqueryMobile with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, android, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an Android app using PhoneGap and JQueryMobile. However I can't get the app to load content in to a div from my server using a jquery method like the following:

```
$("#home").live('pageshow', function(){  
    $("#home .content").load('http://192.168.2.18:8000/m/test/');  
});
```

This code works fine when loaded with safari. Does anyone know why this might be failing when loaded with PhoneGap?

Edit: This only happens with the Android emulator. The iPhone emulator behaves as expected.

Comment: It might have something to do with the good-old same origin policy. see if getJSON with crossdomain capabilities works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using Jquery Full? If so what version?

i had this problem with 1.5.1 of JQuery and Phonegap 0.9.4

I moved back to 1.4.3 Jquery and 0.9.3 Phonegap and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a configuration issue with PhoneGap. Make sure you modify the AndroidManifest.xml file as instructed here so that the app has the necessary permissions. http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart